# Table returns different value depending on index

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a problem, where I am trying to find the number of eigenvalues of a matrix smaller than 1. The matrix has a general form, given by

```
m[n_] := ReplacePart[IdentityMatrix[n/2], {i_, j_} -> Min[i, j] (-1)^(i + j)];
```

where $n$ is even. I've defined the function that counts the number of eigenvalues smaller than 1.

```
f[n_]:= Length[Select[Eigenvalues[f], LessThan[1]]];
```

When I try to construct a table of the number of eigenvalues smaller than 1 for $n =4,6,8,...$ something very weird happens. Mathematica returns different tables depending on the index I use in the table. I.e., the two tables

```
Table[f[m[n]]], {n, 4, 60, 2}]
```

```
Table[f[m[i]]], {i, 4, 60, 2}]
```

are not the same. Has anyone encountered this and does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: In the definition of `f[n_]`, `n` is not used in the body of the function so whatever value of `n` is in scope is used. Try `f[n_] := Length[Select[Eigenvalues[m[n]], LessThan[1]]];`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Block` solves the issue.

`m[n_] := Block[{i, j}, ReplacePart[IdentityMatrix[n/2], {i_, j_} -> Min[i, j] (-1)^(i + j)]];`

Maybe reading the documentation of `Block` and `Module` will shed some light on why this happens.

Comment: No need for `Block`, use `RuleDelayed`.